# WM_CLOSE and IDCANCEL on Win32 DialogBox

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

Sup all, I've a question about the top-right corner X. How does it work on DialogBox?

When I press the top-right corner X for trying to close DialogBox, UINT msg is sent to WM_CLOSE. And WPARAM wParam is sent to IDCANCEL.

I don't understand why WPARAM is sent to IDCANCEL. What is its purpose?

Comment: The `wParam` value isn't used at all for `WM_CLOSE` and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*lparam* and *wparam* are not used on this message.
I know that *lparam* and *wparam* using on msg WM_COMMAND;
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx)